# Slow meteor build performance in docker container

Tags: meteor, docker

The build of a meteor project takes a long time if performed in a docker image (> 30 min) but if done on a local machine ore directly on the server without docker everything works fine (2-10 min).

After some research I still do not know how to tackle this issue. Can anyone provide me with further instruction how to debug my docker? The performance seems really bad.

What should be the minimum server hardware to get a quick build time? The project itself is not large.

Comment: Please add the base docker image that is being used. Share Dockerfile steps if possible. I build my Meteor app in Docker container ... takes around 6-8 mins... which is ok since it also downloads images (no cache usage since build runs on clean box everytime) , updates OS and also installs Meteor ... and then builds it